# Issues installing CentOS 8, suspects issues with NetworkManager to be the reason

Tags: ubuntu, centos, networkmanager

So I am trying to change OS on my server, from Ubuntu 18 to CentOS 8.

I have made an install media for my CentOS 8 on a USB drive. When I boot from the drive on my server the installer always crashes and usually returns an error like:

```
gGLib.Error: g-dbus-error-quark: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: No such interface org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties on object path /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/96
```

Where the last number (in this case 96) can by another number such as `9`. I can also see 100+ network interfaces when changing settings during the installation.

This made me think that there must be an issue with NetworkManager. So I made a bootable ubuntu USB drive, booted it on my laptop and called NetworkManager with `gdbus` and the method GetDevices. It returned three expected interfaces.

I then booted the same USB on my server and ran the same command but then I got:

```
Error: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: No such interface "org.freedesktop.NetworkManager" on object at path /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager
```

This is where I am stuck and I do not know how to continue the troubleshooting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that there is no linux driver for the wireless network card. So physically removing the card solved the issue.